# Why does npm tries to connect to elasticsearch url at compile time?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to compile Node JS project (for CI/CD) using `npm run build` but it failed with the following error

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2023-06-08T14:51:32Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST http://elastic:9200/lyfboat/_search?type=hospitals => getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elastic elastic:9200
      at Log.module.exports.fTNz.Log.error (/usr/src/app/.next/server/pages/doctors/[dynamic].js:77127:56)
      at checkRespForFailure (/usr/src/app/.next/server/pages/doctors/[dynamic].js:2795:18)
      at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/.next/server/pages/doctors/[dynamic].js:13290:7)
      at ClientRequest.wrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4991:19)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Elasticsearch WARNING: 2023-06-08T14:51:32Z
  Unable to revive connection: http://elastic:9200/
```

I am trying to understand **why** `npm run build` tries to connect to elasticsearch url `elastic:9200` at **build time**

**config/elasticsearch.js**

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const esclient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'elastic:9200',
    // log: 'trace'
  });

// export default esclient;
module.exports = esclient
```

Kindly help me to understand this issue

**EDIT**

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the rest of your project. Perhaps your bundler config loads that file

Comment: @CherryDT Sorry, where to check that info?  And Is it possible to disable / supress this behavior ?  Or What should be done to resolve this in a proper way ?

Comment: In your package.json what is `npm run build`?

Comment: @PauloFernando  Updated my question with the required details

Comment: I dont know what to suggest you, but in local testing i got this problem by having the elastic code inside `getStaticProps`, nextJs will make calls in build time if the calls are inside `getStaticProps`